# Pact matchingRules, min and max

Tags: max, min, matching, rules, pact

It seems not possible to mix min and max in the matching rules.

If I use

```
"matchingRules": 
{
    "$.body": 
    {
        "min": 1,
        "max": 2
    },
...
```

only the minimum number of elements will be validated, "max" has no effect.

I've also tried

```
"matchingRules": 
{
    "$.body": 
    {
        "min": 1
    },
    "$.body": 
    {
        "max": 2
    },
...
```

but then only the second rule matches, so the minimum number of elements will not be validated. Is there another possibility to guarantee the minimum and maximum number of elements in an array?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. You can raise an issue in https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-specification/ for this feature to be added in a future specification.